# React loop to make an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have been trying to generate a "simple" array. I have 2 variables I want to do calculations on, and then add result to array in ReactJS.

```
// Import Node Modules
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React, { Component } from "react";

// Variables
const columns = props => props.columns; // is set to 3
const width = props => props.width;     // is set to 300
const Breakpoint = width * columns;
let list ="";

// this should be generated by looping over columns and width like [1*300,2*300,3*300] 

/*
const sizes = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) { 
    sizes.push(width * i)
}
*/

// but this obvisouly doesn't work in react :(


const sizes= [300,600,900]

// Class
{sizes.map(function(size, index){
  list = list + `@media (min-width: ${size}px) { grid-template-columns: repeat(${index + 1}, 1fr);};`
})}

let medias = css`${list}`;

export const GridContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: ${props => props.gap}px;
  ${medias}
`
```

I hope some one can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Given `columns` and `width` are functions, `const Breakpoint = width * columns;` this makes no sense - you cannot multiple a function by a function. The same for `for (i = 0; i < columns; i++) { `. It's not obvious also what this `// Class
{sizes.map(function(size, index){` supposed to do`

Comment: You're also using Array.prototype.map() with the classic (ES5) function syntax... but you have no `return` statement inside the function body.

Comment: width and columns are styled-components props, comes from  <GridContainer columns="3" gap="3" width="300">

Comment: could you edit the code a bit, and put into sandbox? And explain to us what are you expecting to see...https://codesandbox.io/s/q95xq9p0n4

Comment: i've edited the sandbox, so you can see what i'm trying to do /it works, but just wanna gnerate the array sizes[], instead of hardcoding it

Comment: My sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/0q0p1j0y8w

Comment: i figured it out, added working code to my sandbox